# Access to Android Cloud to Device Messaging android?

Tags: android, cloud

Is there any way to start developing and working with the framework without getting access from Google ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now also they didnt give me access to
>   CtDM

C2DM is in a slow rolling beta. I imagine they got thousands of applicants, and they are only going to take on people at a pace that they can support.

> is there any way to start developing
>   and working with the framework without
>   getting access from Google?

No. You are welcome to write your own push framework, but C2DM requires Google servers, and for the beta, your C2DM-enabled Google account needs to be on a whitelist.

Comment: Thanks, iam currently using Xtify and i think i'll have to wait to wprk with google C2DM .

Answer (score 0):

check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888059/371749

devices **need a google account** to use this service! :=)

good luck!