# Android C2DM registering device error [C2DMRegistrar.39] AuthTokenCallback: authFailed

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm getting this error "[C2DMRegistrar.39] AuthTokenCallback: authFailed" when trying to register a device to `google's C2DM`.

Any idea?

- I registered to C2DM.
- I did use the right role email sender I used to register to C2DM.

Comment: Can you post the log cat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure below thing while registering for C2DM

1. You have Market app installed and logged in with one of the Gmail account
2. You have one Gmail account configured

Comment: I had been struggling with C2DM and Urban Airship for a couple of days. It failed to register no matter what I did. Turned out it was because I did not have connection to Google Play which I did not have because my time and date wasn't set (or at least wasn't correct).